# Spring Data REST MongoDB: Joda DateTime representation in REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

My Spring Data MongoDB entity has a property of Joda DateTime type:

```
@JsonProperty("myDate")
private DateTime myDate;
```

With Spring Boot 1.3.6, Spring Data 1.8.4, Spring Data REST 2.4.4 this property gets rendered as

```
"myDate": "2016-09-25T15:58:37.486Z"
```

in the REST representation of my Spring Data entity.

After I have updated the project dependencies to Spring Boot 1.4.1, Spring Data MongoDB 1.9.3, Spring Data REST 2.5.3 I suddenly get my date field represented as

```
"myDate": {
    "content": "2016-09-25T15:58:37.486Z"
},
```

It looks like Joda's DateTime started to get treated as data entity again:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-624

Now I'm wondering how do I get back to my Spring Boot 1.3.6 DateTime representation in REST without downgrading to that Spring Boot version.

**Edit:**

Adding Jackson2 @JsonUnwrapped annotation to the property helps to get representation back:

```
@JsonProperty("myDate")
@JsonUnwrapped
private DateTime myDate;
```

This is a sub-optimal solution for me though, since my properties get auto-generated from JSON schema and I have limited control over generated annotations.

**Edit 2:**

The [Javadoc for the CustomConversions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/CustomConversions.html) class states that

> These types will be considered simple ones (which means they neither
>   need deeper inspection nor nested conversion. Thus the
>   CustomConversions also act as factory for SimpleTypeHolder

Which is in fact not true for Spring Data REST [any more], from what I can tell debugging my code.
The types that are added via default CustomConversions are not treated as simple ones when rendering JSON and properties of those types get serialised as embedded entity objects.

Here is the place in the Spring Data REST [PersistentEntityJackson2Module](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java#L280) that calls to Spring Data MongoDB PersistentEntity implementation to check whether the property type is simple or not. And since the `simpleTypeHolder` in the Spring Data Commons [AbstractMappingContext](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mapping/context/AbstractMappingContext.java#L80) does not contain the types for which Spring Boot auto-configuration adds Joda DateTime converters, the DateTime field is treated as complex object.

**Edit 3:**

Tracking this issue in JIRA:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-907

Comment: hmm what is your question then? It looks like you have a solution for what you are asking?

Comment: I cannot add manually @JsonUnwrapped to all my auto-generated properties. I'd like to have initial SB 1.3.6 behaviour back.
Looking into custom Spring converters now.

Comment: FYI @SergeyShcherbakov, check stackoverflow.com/q/39172792 and  stackoverflow.com/q/39170405 for other threads about this issue. A [ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6881) has already been created for Spring Boot.